# High Voltage negative power supply from positive supplies?

Tags: power-supply, power

How can I combine two identical 5KV 15 ma power supplies that each are set up to deliver 5kv+ with negative being ground, so that they will deliver TWO -5kv outputs (cathode) and the + (anode) being common?   As in a voltage divider.  -5kv to 0 to -5kv

Schematic Please?

Or, how can I take a 5KV 50 ma transformer with a standard two lead secondary, rectify it and filter it to provide two -5KV outputs with + being common or ground?

Comment: Datasheets for the 5kV supplies, please?  Otherwise the question is at a risk of being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question makes no sense since the negative outputs will be taken from the anodes with the cathodes common, with the proviso that the outputs of both supplies are floating.

The answer to your second question is:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I tried to explain it, but apparently I did not make myself clear. I want to run a gas discharge tube that is split in the middle.  Each end is a cathode held at -HV while the center is a pin seal held essentially at ground potential.

Comment: I have two identical 5KV supplies, but they are set up to provide +5KV to an anode and the cathode connection is ground.

Comment: Why can't you connect the gas tube cathodes together and run the thing as a single tube?

Comment: Hi Mr. Fields,Thanks for your help.  This is a metal vapor laser tube.  Metals are vaporized by a heater at the anode and travel by cataphoresis down the tube to each cathode where the metal vapor is caught in cold traps.  These are usually run via two identical supplies.